# Importing .bak file into google cloud sql

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, database-restore

I'm trying to import .bak file from google cloud storage into cloud sql and getting below error

```
generic::invalid_argument: execution of restore command failed with error: {mssql: RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.} Known Issue: presizeDiskForImportHelper: Error doing disk presize check with error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp [::1]:8086: connect: connection refused"
```

I tried to google error but I didn't find any useful information except there is probability the backup file is bad.

Update
The database in cloud SQL is shown with Default collation

when I type

```
Use mydatabase
```

I got

```
Database 'mydatabase' cannot be opened. It is in the middle of a restore.
```

Comment: Are your instances (source and target ) running the same version of SQL server?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand the question. my source is SQL Server 2012. My destination is Cloud SQL SQL Server 2017 Standard

Comment: I read that I may need to do a process called restoration in cloud sql. Any idea what that mean?

Comment: This seems a kind of incompatibility between versions, try to [upgrade your 2012 database to 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/upgrade-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and after export your bak file to Cloud SQL,

Comment: @JanHernandez this is not an option. Based on MS-SQL documentation this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: This looks like an outgoing issue on Cloud SQL, this issue was reported on [this public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/177649982)

Comment: So it seems if reduce the bak file size to ~ 50GB the import work. (original was 150GB)

Comment: Maybe your instnace is running out of space.

Comment: it had 700GB space. (correction file reduced to 5GB not 50GB)

Comment: maybe Could be a good idea add this detail in the tracker

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the disk size of the VM your SQL Server instance is running being too small. If you have an autoscaling disk size, it might still not work. I'm assuming this is because the VM has no reason to scale the disk because it isn't being filled. The `presize check` will probably just look at the disk size and see that it will be too small.

We fixed it by setting the disk size to a fixed size we know is large enough, instead of autoscaling.